# Why does this class declaration not work on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, templates

So I'm trying to get some code that is written for gcc to compile on Visual Studio 2008. I have a problem that I have narrowed down to this:

```
class value_t
{
public:
  typedef std::deque<value_t>         sequence_t;
  typedef sequence_t::iterator        iterator;
};
```

This code fails:

```
1>cpptest.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\deque(518) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'value_t'
1>        c:\temp\cpptest\cpptest.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'value_t'
1>        c:\temp\cpptest\cpptest.cpp(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::deque<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=value_t
1>        ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\deque(518) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'value_t'
1>        c:\temp\cpptest\cpptest.cpp(10) : see declaration of 'value_t'
```

However when I try this with std::vector, it compiles fine:

```
class value_t
{
public:
  typedef std::vector<value_t>        sequence_t;
  typedef sequence_t::iterator        iterator;
};
```

What's wrong? I have tried adding 'typename' everywhere I can think of, but at this point in time I'm thinking it's just a bug in the Dinkumware STL. Can anyone explain what's happening, and/or offer a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Does "everywhere you can think of" include `typedef typename sequence_t::iterator iterator;`?

Comment: You might try a forward declaration before the class declaration.  i.e.  class value_t;

Comment: Well this always happens - right after I post this question, I find the magic combination in google to give me something relevant. See http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=295828 which discusses this topic; still doesn't offer a solution. Can someone confirm that using deque in this situation is non-standard? Is there a way to get this to work without changing the <deque> file?

Comment: @Stephen: yes, but: "error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration".

Comment: @Amardeep: tried that too, doesn't help.

Comment: `typename` doesn't have anything to do with it - the above example isn't a template, so there can't even be a problem with dependent types in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its undefined behavior. See [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/9e0c167ce3a3e336/450be2bbb64bd0d5?lnk=gst&q=vector+self+class#450be2bbb64bd0d5) link on c.l.c++.moderated

Snip from Daniel K's answer :-

> the C++ standard (both C++03 and
>   C++0x) says that what  you are trying
>   causes undefined behaviour, see 
>   [lib.res.on.functions]/2:
>
> "In particular, the effects are
>   undefined in the following  cases: 
>   [..]  — if an incomplete type (3.9) is
>   used as a template     argument when
>   instantiating a template component."

Comment: Thank you, that thread explains it in the most detail I could ever want. Guess I'll have to change the code.

Answer (score 5):

I *think* the problem is that `value_t` is an incomplete type until you reach the end of the definition. Trying to use an incomplete type as the template parameter for a standard container isn't really supposed to work. It can/will happen to work under some circumstances, but if it failed with all standard container types, that still wouldn't signal any kind of bug. The standard requires it to be a complete type, so if it's not, you get what you get -- it probably *should* fail consistently, but if it happens to work, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a class within itself in a template.  How does it resolve this?  I don't know that I have ever tried to do this, but is this even possible?  I don't know why it works for std::vector, but my assumption is that it is wrong.  You are defining a class, and using that definition in the definition.  Seems wrong to me.  Good luck on this one, I'll be interested to see some deeper answers myself...

Comment: It works for std::vector, and on gcc this code compiles fine too. I guess as long as sizeof(class) is known that's enough. It tripped up the people in the link I posted in the comment too, apparently. I've been doing this with vector for years - just a coincidence that it worked then, I guess.